# Why's there no collision?

Tags: java, kotlin, hashmap

I'm studying maps with Kotlin, and decided to run this code:

```
fun main() {
    data class KeyClass(val equals: String, val hash: Int) {
        override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
            return this.equals == (other as KeyClass).equals
        }

        override fun hashCode(): Int {
            return hash
        }

        override fun toString(): String {
            return "($equals,$hash)"
        }
    }

    // collision, since their hashes are the same but they are not equal
    val a1 = KeyClass("a", 1)
    val a2 = KeyClass("b", 1)
    val map = HashMap<KeyClass, String>()
    map[a1] = "value1"
    println(map)
    map[a2] = "value2"
    println(map)

    val map2 = mutableMapOf<KeyClass, String>()
    map2[a1] = "value1"
    println(map2)
    map2[a2] = "value2"
    println(map2)
}
```

which got me:

```
{(a,1)=value1}
{(a,1)=value1, (b,1)=value2}
{(a,1)=value1}
{(a,1)=value1, (b,1)=value2}
```

I thought `HashMap`'s [collision resulted in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692036/3026886). Then when I tried `mutableMapOf` which is Kotlin's `LinkedHashMap`, I didn't get any collision either.

**questions**:

1. What am I missing from this simple collision example?
2. What are the most common collision behaviors per `Map` implementation?

Comment: HashMap can story multiple key-value-paird per key hash. This means that collisions make HashMap slow but it still works, correctly.

Comment: Remember that the contract for [`hashCode()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/hash-code.html) is that equal objects _must_ have equal hash codes; but unequal objects don't _need_ different hash codes — it's perfectly acceptable (though undesirable) for different objects to have the same hash code.  (The [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) are more explicit about this.)  So anything using hash codes (such as maps) must take that into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That list you're talking about is an internal implementation detail. You can't tell* that this is what's happening within the internals of that map, that's the point of encapsulation.

The only way you can observe collision is timing. So, make a million strings, shove them in a map, then run `.containsKey()` a couple of times on an entry that is in there.

Then, repeat the exercise, but this time, make a million objects that collide (same hashcode). Then, again, run `.containsKey()` a couple of times on an entry that is in there.

You'll notice that the second operation returns the exact same answers, but, runs *much* slower, which is the only thing you're going to observe.

*) With timing observations you could surmise it, but that's as far as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a collision. Probably the result is just not what you expect. You're having a hashCode collision which just slows the map's insertion and retrieval times. I think you expect to have the map containing only 1 entry but even though hashcodes match the equals for the keys do not, so you're still putting 2 different keys in the map producing 2 entries.