# Why is there no collision in a HashMap when different keys have the same hash code

Tags: java, kotlin, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I'm trying to create a collision intentionally.

```
 fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   val india = Country("India1", 1000)
   val india2 = Country("India2", 1000)

   val countryCapitalMap: HashMap<Country, String> = hashMapOf()
   countryCapitalMap.put(india, "Delhi1")
   countryCapitalMap.put(india2, "Delhi2")
 }


class Country(var name: String, var population: Long) {

  override fun hashCode(): Int {
      return if (name.length % 2 == 0) 31 else 95
  }

  override fun equals(obj: Any?): Boolean {
      val other = obj as Country?
      return if (name.equals(other!!.name, ignoreCase = true)) true else false
  }
}
```

So, I have `india` and `india2` objects. I've overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods for Country so that:

- `india.hashCode() == india2.hashCode()` --> true
- `india.equals(india2)` --> false

According to [Collision resolution in Java HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691920/collision-resolution-in-java-hashmap) and part of the article ["Lets put this Country objects in hashmap"](https://java2blog.com/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java/#hashcode_and_equals_method), if key1 has result of `hash(key.hashCode())` equal to the same operation on the key2 then there should be collision.

So, I put breakpoint to see content of `countryCapitalMap` and see that its `size` is 2. I.e. it contains two different entries and there is no linkedList. Hence, there is no collision.

**My questions are:**

Why `countryCapitalMap` has a size of `2`? Why is there no collision?

Why doesn't `HashMap` creates a `LinkedList` with two entries with keys that is not equal but have the same hashCode?

Comment: You have a collision, both entries are stored in the same bin, but you won't see it unless you debug the code of HashMap itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are confusing a **collision** - case when hashes of keys are the same (*or to be precise, when hashes are withing the range corresponding to the same bucket of* `HashMap`), with **duplicated keys** *(i.e. keys that are identical according to the* `equals()` *method*). These are two completely different situations.

Under the hood, `HashMap` maintains an array of *buckets*. Each *bucket* corresponds to a range of hash values.

If hashes of the keys collide (*but keys are not equal*) entries (`Node`s to be precise) will be mapped to the same *bucket* and form a linked list, which after a certain threshold will turn into a tree.

Conversely, an attempt to add a new *entry* with a *key* that is already present in a map (*i.e. duplicated key according to the* `equals()` *method*) will result in updating the *value* of the existing *entry*.

Because as you've already observed, `india.equals(india2)` will return `false`, `HashMap` will contain two entries.

And since the hashes of `india` and `india2` are identical, you've succeeded in your intention to create collision. Both entries will be added, both will end up in the same bucket (*i.e. their nodes will form a linked list*).

If you wonder how exactly this *linked list* looks like, take a look at the source code of the `HashMap` class. And you'll find that there's a field `Node<K,V>[] table` - an array of *buckets*, and there's an inner class `Node`:

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next;
}
```

And each *node* holds a reference `next` pointing to the *next node* mapped to the same *bucket* (*if any*).

***Sidenotes :***

- The *hash-function* that you've provided in the example is a bad one. Sure, that's clear that you did that on purpose (*to ensure that two keys would collide*). But it's important to point out that the proper implementation of the `equals/hashCode` contract is crucial for every object that is intended to be used with Collections framework. And for hash-based collections like `HashMap` and `HashSet` the implementation of `hashCode()` is significant to perform well. If hash-function generates a lot of *collisions*, as a consequence many entries could appear in the same *buckets* meanwhile a large number of *buckets* could remain unoccupied. And depending on a *load factor* (*ratio between the occupied and total number of buckets*) your collection might never get resized which will lead to degradation of performance.
- Another thing related to hashes that worth to mention is that the `hashCode()` of the *key* will be invoked *only once*, while a new *node* gets created. Take a look at the code above, and you'll notice that the field `hash` is marked as `final`. That's done on purpose, because computing hash some objects can be costful. Which means that if the state of this *key* changes a `HashMap` will be unaware of that change and will be unable to recognize the same *key*, i.e. if the previous and new hash will differ `equals()` method would not be invoked and `HashMap` will allow the *same key* to appear twice. That leads to another rule of thumb: an object that is used as a *key* should be **immutable**.

Comment: May be worth adding that while the current implementation of `java.util.HashMap` may use linked lists to store chains of elements with the same hash code, that's not the only way to implement a hash table; it could store chains in various other data structures, or it could store all entries directly in the hash table and use various types of probing to locate elements. Wikipedia has [more info on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution). But this is all just implementation detail: it may affect performance, but the user will always see the same results.